# add user in samba server

Tags: samba

```
# smbpasswd -a linuxsir
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
# ls  /etc/samba
gdbcommands  smb.conf  smb.conf.bak  smbpasswd
# groups  linuxsir
linuxsir : linuxsir my_test_group1
root@debian:/home/debian# cat /etc/group
root:x:0:
sambashare:x:119:
root@debian:/home/debian#
# cat /etc/samba/smbpasswd
```

I have add user linuxsir in samba with a password.
1.Why linuxsir is still not in the group sambashare?
2.Why is there nothing in the file /etc/samba/smbpasswd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before `smbpasswd`, you have to create user in Linux with `useradd` and then add the user to proper groups with `usermod`

Adding user to group(s) can be done simultaneously when create the user with `useradd`